# How does Kotlin coroutines manage to schedule all coroutines on the main thread without block it?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I've been experimenting with the Kotlin coroutines in android.  I used the following code trying to understand the behavior of it:

```kotlin
fun onStartButtonPressed(view: View) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Outside Scope: ${Thread.currentThread().id}")

    lifecycle.coroutineScope.launch {
        Log.d(TAG, "Top Level Scope: ${Thread.currentThread().id}")

        val t1 = launch {
            Log.d(TAG, "Task 1 Scope: ${Thread.currentThread().id}")
            for (i in 1..2) {
                delay(1000L)
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    viewBinding.task1ProgressBar.progress = i * 50
                }
            }
        }

        val t2 = launch {
            Log.d(TAG, "Task 2 Scope: ${Thread.currentThread().id}")
            for (i in 1..4) {
                delay(1000L)
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    viewBinding.task2ProgressBar.progress = i * 25
                }
            }
        }

        t1.join()
        t2.join()

        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Completion Scope: ${Thread.currentThread().id}")
            viewBinding.startButton.isEnabled = true
            viewBinding.resetButton.isEnabled = true
            viewBinding.statusTextView.text = "All tasks have been finished."
        }
    }

    viewBinding.statusTextView.text = "All tasks have been started."
    viewBinding.startButton.isEnabled = false
    viewBinding.resetButton.isEnabled = false
}
```

The output of the code is:

```
2021-06-15 21:05:13.066 18079-18079/com.demo.coroutinedemo D/MainActivity: Outside Scope: 2
2021-06-15 21:05:13.132 18079-18079/com.demo.coroutinedemo D/MainActivity: Top Level Scope: 2
2021-06-15 21:05:13.140 18079-18079/com.demo.coroutinedemo D/MainActivity: Task 1 Scope: 2
2021-06-15 21:05:13.142 18079-18079/com.demo.coroutinedemo D/MainActivity: Task 2 Scope: 2
2021-06-15 21:05:17.189 18079-18079/com.demo.coroutinedemo D/MainActivity: Completion Scope: 2
```

This is very wired to me as `join()` method would block the main thread but the UI is not freezing, why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the reason why coroutines were invented and how they differ from threaded concurrency. Coroutines don't block, but suspend (well, they can do both). And "suspend" isn't just another name for "block". When they suspend (e.g. by invoking `join()`), they effectively free the thread that runs them, so it can do something else somewhere else. And yes, it sounds like something that is technically impossible, because we are in the middle of executing the code of some function and we have to wait there, but well... welcome to coroutines :-)

You can think of it as the function is being cut into two parts: before `join()` and after it. First part schedules the background operation and immediately returns. When background operation finishes, it schedules the second part on the main thread. This is **not** how coroutines works internally (functions aren't really cut, they create continuations), but this is how you can easily imagine them working if you are familiar with executors or event loops.

`delay()` is also a suspending function, so it frees the thread running it and schedules execution of the code below it after a specified duration.

Comment: So, the delay method is also suspended, and that's the reason why the main thread can process other tasks?  What if the delay method is a long running task, like image processing, will it still be scheduled on the main thread?  BTW, is there any recommend resources about how coroutines works internally?

Comment: `suspend` functions are supposed to internally ensure that they do not block the thread that they are called from. So if your function does a long-running task, it should delegate that work to a Dispatcher that is intended for that kind of work, and the Dispatcher will internally delegate to an appropriate thread. If you put blocking code directly in a `suspend` function, you are breaking convention and your coroutine will not work correctly (it will block the main thread if called from the Main Dispatcher).

Comment: The most typical way to wrap blocking code to be delegated to an appropriate Dispatcher is to wrap it in a call to `withContext`, where you pass either `Dispatchers.Default` or `Dispatchers.IO` as the context parameter. If you have parallel tasks to run in your suspend function, you would commonly use `coroutineScope` instead of `withContext` and you can launch parallel `async` calls from within it.

Comment: Yes, `delay()` suspends, i.e. it frees the main thread and schedules running the code below it in a 1000ms. Then another task can jump in. If you would replace `delay(1000)` with `Thread.sleep(1000)` you should see that both tasks work sequentially, they take 6000ms to finish and during that time UI blocks (you may need to remove `withContext()`, I'm not sure).